# deleting a character from a file in assembly

Tags: assembly, dosbox

I am using DOSBOX and trying to delete a character from a file.
i have tried replacing the character with a null but that is not working. I also tried replacing the character with 7fh which is DEL in ascii but it doesn't do it as well. any ideas?

Comment: You cannot delete a character from the middle of a file.  What you have to do is to move all characters after the one you want to delete one character ahead.

Comment: There is no system call or anything to do so by the way.  You have to manually copy all the data with read and write calls.

Comment: @fuz: fun fact: some Linux filesystems let you delete from the middle of a file and collapse the range using an `fallocate(FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE)`.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html.  But even that only works when the offset and length are both multiples of the FS block size, not a single character.  As you say, DOS has no equivalent system call.  You can remove a char from the *end* of the file by truncating the length, though.  If DOS has some kind `ftruncate` system call that lets you set a new length?

Comment: @PeterCordes In DOS, file truncation is done by perfoming a write call with a length of 0.  This truncates the file to where the the file pointer currently is.